# Bootstrap Navbar - Keeping some items while collapsing

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to be able to keep some items in my navigation bar while being able to have a collapse toggle when the window gets to small on the right.

EX:
`LOGO    item item item                          Sign In Sign Up`

Collapsed:
`LOGO                                            Sign In Sign Up =`

What's happening:
`LOGO  =                                         Sign In Sign Up`

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl" style="background-color: black">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-left-side collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-nav-right-side">
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Log In</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **responsive ordering** classes as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50099647/bootstrap-4-navbar-keep-section-on-right-even-when-toggled/50099708#50099708).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl" style="background-color: black">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="//placehold.it/300x60" width="300" height="60"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark order-2 order-xl-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-left-side collapse navbar-collapse order-3" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-nav-right-side order-xl-0 order-1">
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Log In</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/Ag7B1WZmDU

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to rearrange your layout. Use the `navbar-toggler` button at the end.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl" style="background-color: black">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"></a>

  <div class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-left-side collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-nav-right-side">
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
  </div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
</nav>
```

---

Alternatively you can use just [`order-last` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#order-classes) on the `navbar-toggler` to rest the order of it. It applies `order: -1`. Normally you need to use more `order-*` classes, but since the `navbar-toggler` is not displayed on large screen you do not need to  do so.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl" style="background-color: black">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark order-last" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-nav navbar-nav-left-side collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-nav-right-side">
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
  </div>
</nav>
```